# Turn and river dealt twice, what is going on?

Tags: omaha, dealing

What is going on in this [Omaha game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdWDN2gDmYQ) at 2:50? Apparently turn and river are dealt twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a cash game, players can, if they agree to it, have multiple run outs of the board when one or more players are all-in.

Basically think of it as two separate hands with the same flop. The idea here is that for the person whom has the higher equity it reduces their chances of outright losing the entire pot, while for the player needing to get lucky it gives them another shot to win some of their money back.

Players can agree to run it out as many times, card permitting, as they want, dividing the pot into the number of runs the players agreed. In this case if you won one of the run outs you win half the pot. It is extremely common in most mid-stakes and higher stake games to have multiple runs. Typically it will be run twice, but 3 or 4 times do happen. I have never dealt a hand where it has been run more than 4 times, but as I said it's up to the players to agree, so if they want more than 4 that's fine.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Really, the commentator of the video should have done that. But it fits into his overall impression.